# Is this a typo or is it intentional? - 'Approve' & 'Reject' in user's suggested edits list

Tags: support, suggested-edits, typographical-error

In the suggested edits list for a given user, this is shown:

[image: Is this okay?]

Now I am wondering why 'Approve' and 'Reject' appear in present simple, shouldn't they be in past simple? (Approved, rejected). Or am I missing something here? This text serves the purpose of telling the status of your edit, so following that logic, it should be in past simple.

Comment: I have a sliiiight suspicion that it reuses the same logic from the "reviews" tab with the only dynamic part of being the "type" name ("reviewed", "suggested"). In the "reviews" tab it makes sense since this is how actions are named as well, but yeah, it looks bizarre on the suggestions tab.

Comment: It's worth noting that the review item on /review already [displays both the action taken _and_ the outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFMSa.png). So yeah, it should probably grab the outcome instead of the action name on the suggestions tab.

Comment: BTW, a little bit out of scope here, but is this okay to be called a 'typo'? Just wondering.